# How to use Moq to mock database method call?

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing, moq

I have question about mock Database. I saw something using moq to mock database call like ExecuteScalar,  ExecuteNonQuery and etc. See the link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/478504/Moq-Mock-Database.

But I am not able to find any information about mock method DiscoverParameters, and ExecuteDataSet.
And repository interface usually a solution for it.

> How can I test the DbCommand execute result code with Moq?

Comment: Can you show the code you're trying to test?

Answer (score 5):

I agree that there could definitely be ways in which the database could be mocked. But the real question is should we? Per my understanding mocking makes sense when you are trying to test behaviors. Aren't or shouldn't database tests be state dependent? If am trying to get number of users from a city, and if I am specifically unit testing my database access layer, I would be much more confident if my C# code actually converts in SQL, fire queries and returns real data. The onus of creating and destroying this data surely lies with the developer. It's a problem to maintain test data, but I think it's a good problem to have and solve.

Mocking the data access layer when you unit test layers that depend on it definitely makes sense. But mocking the database itself while testing the data access layer sounds a) like an over kill b) incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

@user3551790 Hi I have mocked ExecuteDataSet using Moq as below

```
        string connectionString = "server=xx.xx.xx.xx;Trusted_Connection=false;user id=user;password=passowrd;database=DBName;Connect Timeout=360;";
        var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();

        Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.AttributesToAvoidReplicating.Add(typeof(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermissionAttribute));
        DataSet dsResult = new DataSet();
        dsResult.Tables.Add(new DataTable());
        dsResult.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Column1");           
        DataRow dr = dsResult.Tables[0].NewRow();
        dsResult.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
        dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray = new object[] { DBNull.Value};
        dsResult.Tables.Add(new DataTable());      

        var mockDb = new Mock<SqlDatabase>(connectionString);
        mockDb.Setup(a => a.GetStoredProcCommand("SP_NAME")).Returns(command);
        mockDb.Setup(a => a.ExecuteDataSet(command)).Returns(dsResult);
```

However since DiscoverParameters is a non virtual method you cannot mock it using Moq. You will have to go for Typemock